# How to extract single string and delete other, similar in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I combine category name with skill name to sort it by category name. Now I have table with column as below

```
(Category1) Skill 1
(Category1) Skill 2
(Category1) Skill 3
(Category1) Skill 4
(Category1) Skill 5
(Category1) Skill 6
(Category2) Skill 7
(Category2) Skill 8
(Category2) Skill 9
(Category2) Skill 10
(Category2) Skill 11
(Category2) Skill 12
```

I want to leave just one category header per first skill and delete other, similar to have table like this one

```
(Category1) Skill 1
Skill 2
Skill 3
Skill 4
Skill 5
Skill 6
(Category2) Skill 7
Skill 8
Skill 9
Skill 10
Skill 11
Skill 12
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the strings and retrieve the last part `Skill x`, as well as check where `Categoryx` is duplicated, and use the result to replace with the splitted part:

```
import numpy as np

m = df.col1.str.split(r'\) ', expand=True)
df['col1'] = np.where(m.duplicated(subset=0), m[1], df.col1)

               col1
0   (Category1) Skill 1
1               Skill 2
2               Skill 3
3               Skill 4
4               Skill 5
5               Skill 6
6   (Category2) Skill 7
7               Skill 8
8               Skill 9
9              Skill 10
10             Skill 11
11             Skill 12
```

---

Input data -

```
 col1
0    (Category1) Skill 1
1    (Category1) Skill 2
2    (Category1) Skill 3
3    (Category1) Skill 4
4    (Category1) Skill 5
5    (Category1) Skill 6
6    (Category2) Skill 7
7    (Category2) Skill 8
8    (Category2) Skill 9
9   (Category2) Skill 10
10  (Category2) Skill 11
11  (Category2) Skill 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your dataframe(df) column is called 'A':

```
df2 = df.A.str.split(expand=True)
df2[0]=df2[0].mask(df2[0].eq(df2[0].shift())).fillna('')]
df.A = df2.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```